# Multi-column, multi-line footer in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to create a footer in a document where the left side shows the authors and the right side shows the title.  Sometimes, one or both of these might be long enough that they cover multiple lines.  [This page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/2-column-footers/13e2f24b-0bcc-417b-abfa-917d0b2ec36e) has the best list of methods I've seen, but unfortunately the only one that seems to reasonably handle the scenario I've provided, inserting a two-column table in the footer, also requires adding a new paragraph below the table, and so takes up extra whitespace.  Is there another option?

Comment: Why down vote question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no better option.

You **can change the size of that paragraph mark** following the table , though. Select it and change the size to 1 point. *(You will need to type this number.)*